# Exif Information Rotation getting file not found exception

Tags: android, exif

I have been trying to figure out EXIF for awhile and I just have had issue after issue, after issue. I am hoping someone can shed some light on this for me.

I have a button that a user pressed and it does this intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

The PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST is as follows

```
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
```

Here is my OnActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        mMediaUri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), mMediaUri);

            String fileName2 = FileHelper.getFileName(UserProfileActivity.this, mMediaUri, "image");
            try {
                ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(fileName2);
                int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);
                System.out.println(orientation + "---------------------------");
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                if (orientation == 6) {
                    System.out.println("oritation 6, rotate 90");
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                } else if (orientation == 3) {
                    System.out.println("oritation 3, rotate 180");
                    matrix.postRotate(180);
                } else  if (orientation == 8) {
                    System.out.println("oritation 8, rotate 270");
                    matrix.postRotate(270);
                }
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            //friendsProfilePic imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            if (userChangedImage){
                userProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            userProfileImageEditProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            final ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryUser = ParseUser.getQuery();
            try {
                byte[] fileBytes = FileHelper.getByteArrayFromFile(UserProfileActivity.this, mMediaUri);
                if (fileBytes == null) {
                    //there was an error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was an error. Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    fileBytes = FileHelper.reduceImageForUpload(fileBytes);
                    String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(UserProfileActivity.this, mMediaUri, "image");
                    userChangedImageFile = new ParseFile(fileName, fileBytes);
                    userChangedImage = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this is what is reading inside of the console.

```
System.out: image.png (No such file or directory)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: You should debug your code and see what data.getData() actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`FileHelper.getFileName()` is almost assuredly wrong, as there is no requirement for the `Uri` to represent a file. I strongly encourage you to get rid of it entirely.

Use a `ContentResolver` (from `getContentResolver()` on your `Activity`) and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. You can pass that to [a constructor on the support library edition of `ExifInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)) to attempt to get the orientation tag, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You should use compat ExifInterface.

`com.android.support:exifinterface:${lastLibVersion}`

You will be able to instantiate the ExifInterface(pior API <24) with `InputStream` (from `ContentResolver`) instead of uri paths avoiding "File not found exceptions"

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html